# Django. Import module error. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'

Tags: django, import, module

This is very simple. I have a new project with these files:

[image]

in my urls file, how can I import the `home.views`?

I thought this would work:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from website.home import views  <---

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

But when I runserver o makemigrations or anything I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'website.home'

I am clueless. Plz help. I have included 'home' in INSTALLED APPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the project name when you import, just

```
from home import views
```

should work fine.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question. It was a problem with pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

you should write like this if you have more then one class named views

```
from home import views as home_views
```